# Read many .sas7bdat files via a loop in R

Tags: r, loops, load

I am a noob in R and a experience a lot of trouble with the following:
I have to read in over 200 datasets and I want to do this automatically. I wrote some code that works perfectly for Rdata extensions but if I try it for SAS-files it always blocks...

path= "road"

```
# I make a list of all the different paths of all the files in my folder

File_pathnames <- list.files (path= Road, pattern = "*.sas7bdat", full.names=T)

# I create an empty list

list.data<-list()


# I try to run a loop to load all the SAS files:

for (i in 1: length(File_pathnames))
{
 list.data[[i]] <- read_sas(File_pathnames[i])
}
```

Problem: it does not load the tables into my global environment (when I used the rdata files I used the load function and all the data appeared in the global environment). How Can I solve this?

many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your data ARE in the global environment, as elements of `list.data` (check `list.data[[1]]`, `list.data[[2]]`, ...)

The issue you have is linked to the fact that `load` loads an object in the environment using the name it had when it was saved. As an example

```
x <- 10
save(x, file='tmp')
rm(x)
x
load('tmp')
x
```

save `x` and reload it, while `read_sas` only load the data that you have to assign to a variable.

If you want to assign specifically each data set, you have to define a name for each of them and assign the data. Your loop would look like

```
for (i in 1: 1: length(File_pathnames))
{
  namei <- paste0("name",i)
  data <- read_sas(File_pathnames[i])
  assign(namei, data)
}
```

and your data would be stored in "name1", "name2", ...

Answer (score 0):

You should the assign each SAS files read in `File_pathnames[i]` as an object named `FilenamesS[i]`. Try

```
for (i in 1: length(File_pathnames))
{
 data <- read_sas(File_pathnames[i])
 assign (FilenamesS[i], data)
 }
```